# Condition_Signal() in threads, How it works?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex

Let's take a look at the following code:

```
cond_t c;
mutex_t m;
int queue_size = 0;

void enqueue(item x) {
  mutex_lock(&m);
  /* add x to tail */
  queue_size++;
  cond_signal(&c); // Line 1
  mutex_unlock(&m);
}
item dequeue() {
  mutex_lock(&m);
  if (queue_size == 0)
     cond_wait(&c, &m); // Line 2
  /* remove from head */
  queue_size--;
  mutex_unlock(&m);
}
```

From what I read `cond_wait(&c, &m);` doesn't do busy waiting (It sends current thread to sleep if `m` is locked).

Now suppose thread t1 is in line1 while thread t2 is in line 2. t1 sends signal so t2 will wake up, but since it's still locked then t2 will go back to sleep, then t1 will release the mutex but t2 is still sleep and none waked it up again so it will never run.

How is this possible? Did I make wrong conclusions?

Comment: "It sends current thread to sleep if m is locked" this is wrong, m must be always locked ta this point and it always puts thread in sleeping and unlocks mutex at the same time.

Comment: You tagged this post "C++". Is that really C++ code? or is it C code? You should not be using Posix threads (pthreads) in a C++ program. You should be using `std::thread`, `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable`, etc. instead.

Comment: @Slava if it can unlock the mutex then it can continue without waiting, that doesn't make sense

Comment: It does make sense if you understand how it works. You do not need condition variable to wait for mutex to be released, you just lock the mutex and you will sleep until you can acquire it. A condition variable waits for condition hense the name, not for the mutex.